# SKReceiptRequest not calling (NSBundle that conforms to) SKRequestDelegate

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase, objective-c-category, receipt

I am currently implementing local receipt validation following Apple's *Receipt Validation Programming Guide*. I have defined a category on `NSBundle` that conforms to `SKRequestDelegate` and that offers a method for receipt validation, which I call from inside `main()` before it initializes the application delegate and passes it to `UIApplicationMain()`. This is what the documentation says:

> Perform receipt validation immediately after your app is launched,
>   before displaying any user interface or spawning any child processes.
>   Implement this check in the main function, before the
>   NSApplicationMain function is called.

When there is no receipt at `self.appStoreReceiptURL`, my method for receipt validation prepares an `SKReceiptRequest` with properties as follows and sets itself as delegate. Since it conforms to `SQRequestDelegate` it implements both `requestDidFinish:` and `request:didFailWithError:`.

```
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @NO, SKReceiptPropertyIsExpired,
                            @NO, SKReceiptPropertyIsRevoked,
                            @NO, SKReceiptPropertyIsVolumePurchase,
                            nil];
```

The odd thing is that neither of the two methods is called after the category starts the request while the app is running in the Xcode debugger. What could explain this? How can I receive (refresh) a receipt during development preferably with a category on `NSBundle`? Is it perhaps to early to send the request before the application delegate has come into existence (despite of what the cited documentation indicates)? Is there any working sample code that I could consult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if there were several reasons why this failed, the use of the category (at this time) being one of them. If I make the following changes I receive callbacks to `requestDidFinish:` and can make progress:

- Launch the app in the debugger on a physical device, not the simulator. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255654/i-am-getting-error-while-requesting-products-from-app-store-for-iap) StoreKit (and in-app purchaseses) will not work in the simulator. This is documented in [Xcode 5.1.1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH2-SW293).)
- Let a object [owned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399991/how-can-i-declare-a-private-property-within-a-named-category) by the category (not the category itself) conform to `SKRequestDelegate`. (I would like to understand why this is an apparent requirement, but currently do not.)
- [Retain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095367/in-app-purchase-response-never-comes/9468562#comment38293219_9468562) both the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` and its `SKRequestDelegate` during the entire duration of the request. Retaining either one but not the other is apparently insufficient. (Notice that `SKRequest` does not maintain a `strong` link to the [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retain).)